# Integrating with Azure API apps. Login and pass cookie/token to server from angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, azure, azure-api-apps

I am implementing an Angular 1 frontend to call an [Azure API app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/api/). I am given swagger site as documentation. To access the docs, I need to login with Google first, after that, calls made from swagger are authenticated.

But the thing is how does this work? I know it uses cookies as I checked the Chrome developer tool and see a cookie is passed? But how do I correctly implement this in Angular? Like I cannot expect users to login using the swagger site then come to my frontend. Whats the correct way to use an Azure API app?

Usually to use Google auth on an API, I will get id token from Google and pass it to server to get and app token which I use on subsequent requests, does Azure API apps do it differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Google Auth client SDK for JS to integrate Google SSO in your application for acquiring `access token`, which we can set in HTTP requests' `authorization` header, for calling the APIs protected by Google.

We can leverage the sample on https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#authorizing-and-making-authorized-requests, and leverage [`GoogleUser.getAuthResponse()`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetauthresponse) function to acquire access token.

Here is a code snippet:

```
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
    <script>
        function handleClientLoad() {
            gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
          }
        function initClient() {
            gapi.client.init({
                apiKey: '<api_key>',
                discoveryDocs: ["https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"],
                clientId: '<clint_id>.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                scope: 'profile'
            }).then(function () {
              // Listen for sign-in state changes.
              gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

              // Handle the initial sign-in state.
              updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
            });
          }
          function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
            // When signin status changes, this function is called.
            // If the signin status is changed to signedIn, we make an API call.
            if (isSignedIn) {
              makeApiCall();
            }
          }

          function handleAuthClick(event) {
            // Ideally the button should only show up after gapi.client.init finishes, so that this
            // handler won't be called before OAuth is initialized.
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
          }

          function handleSignoutClick(event) {
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
          }

          function makeApiCall() {
            var user = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get()
            var authinfo = user.getAuthResponse();
            var access_token = authinfo.access_token
            console.log(authinfo)
            sessionStorage.setItem('access_token',access_token);
          }
        var app = angular.module('adalDemo', []);
        // using '!' as the hashPrefix but can be a character of your choosing
        app.controller('homeController', function($scope, $location, $http) {
            $scope.getinfo = () => {
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://garyapi.azurewebsites.net/contacts/1',
                    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem("access_token")}
                }).then((data)=>{
                    console.log(data);
                })
            }

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried something similar, basically setting the Authorization header with the token, the server does not appear to see that. Or its not considering the request authenticated and tries to redirect user to google again. Is looking into the Authorization header a standard azure api app behavior? Or isit something the server dev needs to configure?

Comment: Is your authenticated protection is set by Azure Web Apps' protal under `Authentication / Authorization` section? And could you share your error messages with us?